# This tag [belongs-on] another site

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, synonym-request

The tag [belongs-on](/questions/tagged/belongs-on) (currently 6 questions, all of them asked in 2011 or earlier) seems to be a very old way to refer to what are now known as [migration](/questions/tagged/migration) close reasons.

[belongs-on](/questions/tagged/belongs-on) should be a synonym of [migration](/questions/tagged/migration).

Comment: To add, all the questions using the tag are either closed or up for closure.

Comment: [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20717/282094) (and it's deleted answer) which was the second use of the tag (and additionally mod-tagged) tells of instances of usage incompatible with the proposed synonym.

Comment: If it's only 6 question, manual retagging would suffice I think?

Answer (score 6):

I'd argue for retagging and removing it - since the tag on its own is a meta tag. There's no real value for it on its own.

---

I've retagged the questions, though looking through them, migration wasn't always the right tag. I've gone with [migration-path-request](/questions/tagged/migration-path-request) in some cases, and completely different tags on another.

Some of the questions were confusing, referring to a primodial meta.stackexchange that predated the Meta.Stackoverflow that became Meta.Stackexchange (and not the Meta.Stackoverflow we have now), and didn't really have any historical value on their own so were deleted.

Comment: _“since the tag on its own is a meta tag”_ — are you talking about the MSE [tag:belongs-on] tag or the [various instances of `belongs-on-*` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2168430/2) ([<10k screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLKYx.png)) on the trilogy sites?

Comment: Yes. But that's an issue for the sites in question, of which Super User is my concern.